# Akka cluster and OpenShift

Tags: scala, akka, openshift

I'm new to Akka Clusters, however as I am understanding its documentation, I need to know at least one "seed node" to join an existing cluster.

So when using clusters with OpenShift I would need to know if the current gear is the first node - then I would create a new cluster - or if there are already some other gears around - I would need to know at least one of their IPs to join them.

Is this possible with OpenShift cloud? *(I'm using the DIY catridge, so customizing the start up script wouldn't be a problem. However I can't find any environment variable which provides me relevant data.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DIY gears on OpenShift Online do not scale.  And if you are spinning up separate applications for each of the nodes in your cluster, you are going to (probably) run into inter-gear communication issues.  You might need to create your own akka cartridge (http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html), then you can set your own scaling options.  You might check out this cartridge (https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart) which supports scaling and might give you some ideas about how to implement yours.